# FreePascal console video rows and columns

Tags: linux, windows, console, screen, freepascal

I'm looking for a method to get the number of console video rows and columns under FPC.  I'm looking for the most portable way, but at least one that will work under Windows (and preferably also under Linux) will do.

From the old Turbo Pascal days, I had written below functions but they won't compile under FPC, and being in assembler they are not very portable.

```
//Return the number of video rows
function GetVideoY: Byte; assembler;
asm
  mov     ax,$40
  mov     es,ax
  mov     al,es:$84
  inc     al
end; { GetVideoY }

//Return the number of video columns
function GetVideoX: Byte; assembler;
asm
  mov     ax,$40
  mov     es,ax
  mov     al,es:$4A
end; { GetVideoX }
```

UPDATE:
Based on the correct answer's suggestions the above routines become:

```
//Return the number of video rows
function GetVideoY: Byte;
begin
  GetVideoY := WindMaxY - WindMinY + 1;
end;

//Return the number of video columns
function GetVideoX: Byte;
begin
  GetVideoX := WindMaxX - WindMinX + 1;
end;
```

I tried them both on Windows and Linux and they seem to work OK. Thanks.

Comment: Your asm functions doesn't compile because the assembler mode is not specified: **{$ASMMODE   intel}**. They look like being written in the 16 bit age. Try to convert the registers: **ax**->**eax**, **es**->**esp**. **al** is still ok because it matches the result size (8 bits). Otherwise you can have a look at the **crt** unit.

Comment: @user3661500 conversion es->esp is wrong as es is a segment register and segment register names did not change. OP is trying to read bytes at the absolute memory addresses 40:004A and 40:0084 in the ROM-BIOS data area (http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0093.HTM)

Comment: The original code used BIOS addresses to obtain this information.  But this is irrelevant as what matters is to have the equivalent functionality, not how that is achieved.  For example, maybe there is Windows and/or Linux API call that gives columns and rows for the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the old Turbo Pascal days what had change a lot is that reading text screen resolution from the ROM-BIOS data area makes sense almost only in bare-bone Operating Systems, where the [Dan Rollins's TECH Help!](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0093.HTM) absolute addresses still hold and Free Pascal conversion of your code would look like

```
function GetVideoY: Byte;
begin
  GetVideoY := mem[$40:$84] + 1;
end;

function GetVideoX: Byte;
begin
  GetVideoX := mem[$40:$4a];
end;
```

Console applications running under OSes with Graphical User Interface frequently don't share the screen with other applications directly and don't use BIOS video calls to draw on the screen. Instead they usually run behind a virtualization API.

Free Pascal has a compatibility API for console application in the form of `Crt` unit

> Source: http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/crt/index.html
>
> ..the CRT unit for Free Pascal, both under dos linux and Windows. The unit was first written for dos by Florian klaempfl. The unit was ported to linux by Mark May and enhanced by Michael Van Canneyt and Peter Vreman. It works on the linux console, and in xterm and rxvt windows under X-Windows. The functionality for both is the same..

You can see what is on it's surface (portable API) at

- http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/packages/rtl-console/src/inc/crth.inc
- http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/packages/rtl-console/src/inc/crt.inc

You can see what is inside at

- MsDos (FreeDos) **(retro)**

  - http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/packages/rtl-console/src/msdos/crt.pp
- Windows

  - http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/packages/rtl-console/src/win/video.pp
  - http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/packages/rtl-console/src/win/crt.pp
  - ...
- Linux

  - http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/packages/rtl-console/src/unix/video.pp
  - http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/packages/rtl-console/src/unix/crt.pp
  - ...
- and some other systems

  - http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpc/trunk/packages/rtl-console/src/

Equivalent expressions for the current screen resolution should be

```
WindMaxY - WindMinY + 1
```

and

```
WindMaxX - WindMinX + 1
```

and reading docs around [GotoXY](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/crt/gotoxy.html) might be a good place to start and searching for text `ScreenWidth` and `ScreenHeight` in the source code files can tell you anything else you may want to know